# Need some control of Previous/Next buttons on keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ipad, keyboard

I am working with iScroll for an iPad web-app. When a user touches the next button (on top of the keyboard) focus jumps to a form element on another slide it breaks the scroller.

I have tried putting each slide in a separate form tag so it would grey out "next" when the end of the form is reached. This yielded no results and the button still jumps across slides.

How can I remove the Prev/Next buttons or at least define boundaries for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been trying to come up with an answer myself for a few days now. It seems the next/back buttons traverse **all** input elements visible on the page (they don't even have to be in the same / any form).

The best solution I've been able to come up with is to disable the input elements you don't want traversed.

Comment: That is what I ended up having to do as well.